# Display "Cannot find iBeacon" message

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, ibeacon

My question is very simple. I would like to display an error message i.e. "Cannot find iBeacon" if iBeacon monitoring fails, after calling `startSearchingForSessions` via a button press after being called in `viewDidLoad`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    if self.locationManager.responds(to: #selector(CLLocationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization)) {
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false

    let uuid = UUID(uuidString: "869A6E2E-AE14-4CF5-8313-8D6976058A7A")
    self.beaconRegion = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: uuid!, identifier: "com.dejordan.myapp"
    startSearchingForSessions()

}

func startSearchingForSessions() {

    // Start looking for the beacons with that UUID and Identifier.
    self.locationManager.startMonitoring(for: self.beaconRegion)
    self.locationManager.startRangingBeacons(in: self.beaconRegion)
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

}
```

And handling the found beacons thusly:

```
// Required by the Location Manager.
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
    self.locationManager.startRangingBeacons(in: self.beaconRegion)
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didDetermineState state: CLRegionState, for region: CLRegion) {
    if state == CLRegionState.outside {
        print("Cannot Find Beacon")
    }
}

// Required by the Location Manager.
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion) {
    self.locationManager.stopRangingBeacons(in: self.beaconRegion)
}

// This is called if any beacons are found.
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], in region: CLBeaconRegion) {

    var result = Array<CLBeacon>()
    for beacon in beacons {
        result.append(beacon)
    }

    foundBeacons = result
    // If we found any, we need to see
    // what class they belong to based on information
    // from Parse.
    self.identifyFoundBeacons()

    // We can stop looking for beacons now.
    self.locationManager.stopMonitoring(for: self.beaconRegion)
    self.locationManager.stopRangingBeacons(in: self.beaconRegion)
    self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

}
```

I have implemented the delegate error methods in an attempt to find where this occurs but thus far in navigating the mounds of documentation on iBeacon I have come up fruitless.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    print("Location manager failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, monitoringDidFailFor region: CLRegion?, withError error: Error) {
    print("Failed monitoring region: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: as per your code func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, monitoringDidFailFor region: CLRegion?, withError error: Error) {
    print("Failed monitoring region: \(error.localizedDescription)")
} is right to detect fails in beacon monitor fail

Comment: You can use UIAlertController to show the message. Make sure that the call to show the UIAlertController is in the UI Thread (main thread) : https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ios/874/uialertcontroller#t=201706140716504655358

Comment: Do you ever see the dialog for `requestWhenInUseAuthorization()`, and are you sure it is granted?  You must also have bluetooth turned on and location turned on for your phone.

Comment: yeah, I'm not having any trouble finding the iBeacon, I just cannot catch when it _cannot_ find the iBeacon

Comment: to my surprise, turns out didRangeBeacons is the method I was looking for, even though it returns an empty array, I can use the size to determine whether or not any beacons were found. Thank you for the help regardless!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly enough, `didRangeBeacons` in the delegate method

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], in region: CLBeaconRegion)
```

gets called with an empty array of `[CLBeacon]`s, wherein I can use the `beacons` array size to determine whether or not any beacons were found.

Not what I expected, but this has solved my problem!

Answer (score 2):

If you simply want to know when beacons are not detected (vs. when there was a low-level failure to look for beacons), then simply use the following delegate method:

```
public func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didDetermineState state: CLRegionState, for region: CLRegion) {
  if state == CLRegionState.outside {
    print("Cannot find beacon")
  }
}
```

Comment: hmmm.... it seems it's not catching there. I have a button attached to the `.start` functions posted earlier, and on every press after a few seconds nothing happens

Comment: Can you augment your question to show your full code where you set up your LocationManager and delegate?  Have you requested location permission?  Can you show that code?